# Set Global Variable from Callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-modules

First I need to fetch data by using 'request', then add response to variable firstData :

```
var request = require('request');
let firstData,otherData = '';
request({
    url: 'https://someurl.extension/get/data',
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: {}
  },(error, response) => {
   firstData = response;
  })
```

then I make another request to get otherData's value :

```
request({
    url: 'https://someurl.extension/get/otherdata',
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: {}
  },(error, response) => {
   otherData = response;
  })
```

then render them up with 
`res.json({firstData,otherData})`
but nothing showed up, because async can't do that. Some said it should be done by 'callback', but what if I need to make like 5 requests or more? There will be 5 callback and the code is not beautiful anymore.
Is there any way on doing this? or is there any way to put response to global vars? something like `setState()` in reactjs.
Thanks.

Comment: In Javascript, any time you're trying to assign an asynchronous response to a higher scoped variable, you are probably doing things wrong.  That's a major warning that the code is wrong.  The timing of the data is ONLY known inside the callback so that's really the only place it can be used or in a function you call from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can promisify `request` or just use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), and then use `async/await`

```
const request = require('request-promise');

app.get('/some-route', async(req, res) => {
                      // ^^ Notice async keyword
    try {

        const firstData = await request({
            url: 'https://someurl.extension/get/data',
            method: "POST",
            json: true,
            body: {}
        });

        const otherData = await request({
            url: 'https://someurl.extension/get/otherdata',
            method: "POST",
            json: true,
            body: {}
        });

        res.json({
            firstData,
            otherData
        })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500);
        res.send('Error');
    }

});
```

If you can perform request in parallel, (If they do not depend on each other), you can use `Promise.all`

```
const [firstData, secondData] = await Promise.all([
     request(/* first request options  */),
     request(/* second request options */)
]);
```

Comment: `await is only valid in async function`. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Check my route callback function, notice `async` keyword.

Comment: I'd like to add that, when the two requests don't depend on the results of one another, it's good practice to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve them simultaneously

Comment: Indeed @kingdaro, updated the answer with that detail

Comment: What error are you getting, show the stack trace, and your actual code.